# ImageIcon slow in ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, performance, jcombobox, imageicon, listcellrenderer

I have a `class GridPanel extends JPanel`, with a static inner class `ToolSelectComboBox extends JComboBox`, which in turn has two static inner classes `ToolSelectComboBoxModel implements ComboBoxModel` and `ToolSelectComboBoxRenderer implements ListCellRenderer`. The panel displays the `ToolSelectComboBox` (TSCB), whose constructor sets its model and the renderer to be the custom ones I created. The box is created correctly, and its models and renderers work correctly.

However, the Renderer's `getListCellRendererComponent(...)` method uses an `ImageIcon` on the `JLabel` that it returns. The icon is loaded correctly, but, the first time I click the combo box (on each run), the image takes <s>exactly (or at least very very close to)</s> a little more than a second to load. I would assume that this is some lag in loading the file, except that

- It is a 4kB file on my local file system
- When I add `System.out.println` commands before and after the `result.setIcon(...)` command, they follow each other almost instantly.

The strange thing that I notice is that the `println` commands are fired *twice*, once when I click the box, and again when the icon loads.

It may also be worth noting that, as this designed to work with multiple classes that override a single method of the parent abstract class (to generate the path to the icon), when I noticed that this was working slowly, I changed the code from simply retrieving the icon with the `getIcon` command to storing the various sized icons (16, 32, and 64 px squared) in a `TreeMap<Tool.ImageSize, ImageIcon>` (where `Tool` is an interface I created that has a `ImageIcon getIcon()` method.

All my imports are in order.

Any help would be appreciated!

I apologize if I have posted too much code, but I wanted to make sure that it's understandable. On the other hand, if more code would be required for you to understand, please don't hesitate to ask.

Code (all lines that begin with "`*`" and have comment-like text are collapsed JavaDoc tags, not just messed-up code):

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel {

    public static class ToolSelectComboBox extends JComboBox {

         // Combo box model `ToolSelectComboBoxModel` snipped

         * A renderer for the {@link ToolSelectComboBoxModel}. This may
        public static class ToolSelectComboBoxRenderer implements
                ListCellRenderer {

             * The default renderer. Only the icon and text are modified.
            protected DefaultListCellRenderer d = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(final JList list,
                    final Object value, final int index,
                    final boolean isSelected, final boolean cellHasFocus) {
                if (!ToolSelectComboBoxModel.class.isInstance(list.getModel())) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(
                            "Cannot use a ToolSelectComboBoxRenderer on any list model type other than ToolSelectComboBoxModel.");
                }
                final JLabel result = (JLabel) d.getListCellRendererComponent(
                        list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                result.setText(null);
                if (value != null) {
                    result.setIcon(((Tool) value)
                            .getIcon(Tool.IconSize.SIZE_32PX));
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public ToolSelectComboBox() {
            setModel(new ToolSelectComboBoxModel());
            ((ToolSelectComboBoxModel) getModel()).add(new CircleTool()); // shown below
            setRenderer(new ToolSelectComboBoxRenderer());
        }
    }

     * Create the panel.
    public GridPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        final ToolSelectComboBox toolSelectComboBox = new ToolSelectComboBox();
        add(toolSelectComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final SquareGrid squareGrid = new SquareGrid(); // another class; this works fine
        add(squareGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER); // irrelevant to problem

    }

}
```

The `CircleTool` class only has one method (to override `AbstractTool`'s abstract method to get the image *path*) and, since the method works (it gets the path fine, it's just the icon that loads slowly), I have not included this class.

The `AbstractTool` class:

```
public abstract class AbstractTool implements Tool {

    /**
     * A {@link TreeMap} to map the icon sizes to their icons.
     */
    protected final TreeMap<Tool.IconSize, ImageIcon> map = new TreeMap<Tool.IconSize, ImageIcon>();

    /**
     * Constructs the tool and sets up the {@linkplain #map}.
     */
    public AbstractTool() {
        for (final Tool.IconSize size : Tool.IconSize.values()) {
            System.out.println("Putting value for " + size);
            map.put(size,
                    new ImageIcon(Tool.class.getResource(getImagePath(size))));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ImageIcon getIcon(final IconSize size) {
        return map.get(size);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the image path for the given image size.
     * 
     * @param size
     *            the size
     * @return the image path
     */
    protected abstract String getImagePath(Tool.IconSize size);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but, the first time I click the combo box (on each run), the image takes a little more than a second to load. I would assume that this is some lag in loading the file

That would be my guess as well.

> except that when I add System.out.println commands before and after the result.setIcon(...) command, they follow each other almost instantly

When you click on the combo box all the code runs on the EDT which means each Icon would be loaded sequentially.

However System.out.println() runs on a separate Thread so it is displayed immediately.

The solution is to load the icons at program start up. That is whenever  you define/add the Icons to your map you should read them in at that time. You may want to do that on a separate Thread so you don't block the GUI from displaying.

Edit:

Here is a simple SSCCE that displays icons in a combo box:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxIcon extends JFrame
{
    JComboBox comboBox;

    public ComboBoxIcon()
    {
        Object[] items =
        {
            new ImageIcon("about16.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("add16.gif"),
            new ImageIcon("copy16.gif")
        };
        comboBox = new JComboBox( items );
        getContentPane().add( comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

If you need more help then you need to post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks for responding! What you're saying about the `println` command running on a separate Thread makes sense; I hadn't thought of that. However, what is the event dispatching thread? The wikipedia article doesn't make it clear to me and I'm fairly new to Java (and am used to C++, which I have heard is a hassle to transfer from), so pardon my ignorance :). I assumed that by putting the `ImageIcon`s in my `TreeMap`, the icons would automatically load; is this not the case? If not, how would I do so? `loadImage()` is protected; should I use `getImage()`?

Comment: I tried `getImage()` and the lag time still occurred, both within a new `Thread` and in the default `Thread`. What would you suggest I do? Should I just create a graphics object and paint the icon to it?

Comment: Yes creating the ImageIcon should cause the image to be loaded. It is not apparent from your code when or how you do this. So I don't know if this is being done when you create and display the GUI, or whether it happens when the combo box is clicked. It appears to be the latter. The EDT is the Event Dispatch Thread. All updates to the GUI should execute on this Thread. Read up on [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. I included my SSCCE that shows icons render immediately when preloaded.

Comment: that's really strange; I use essentially the same code: `new ImageIcon(Tool.class.getResource(getImagePath(size)))`, where `getImagePath(...)` returns a String, so we're both passing a `URL` to the `ImageIcon` constructor. I read what the `SSCCE.org` website but I really have no idea how I would make a SSCCE for this issue. The entire code is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27175416/tools.vgrid2.zip).

Comment: @kleopatra, what I mean is if you have looping code that executes on the EDT and updates the text of a label and then invokes Thread.sleep(), you will only ever see the last value set on the label, not all the intermediate valued because you cause the EDT to sleep. However, if you invoke System.out.println() to print the same text you will see the output every iteration of the loop, because it executes on a separate Thread.

Comment: Sorry - I just realized I forgot to accept your answer. Thanks for your help!